# Fastest way to initialize object - PHP performance

Tags: php

I have an object that contains around 30 settings.
1 page can contain 10 objects that have max 15 settings each. 
To initialize the object, I get an associative array from the database for each object.
I am wondering what would be the best performance? I currently have (example):

```
$object = new element_class();
$array = <query from database>
//Reinitialize object to remove any set values of object properties to null
foreach($object as $key=>$value)
{
    $object->$key = null;
}

//Switch of array to set the values in the array in the object properties
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    switch($key)
    {
        case 'a':
         $this->property_a = $value;
         break;
        case 'b':
         $this->property_b = $value;
         break;
        case 'c':
         $this->property_c = $value;
         break;
        case 'd':
         $this->property_d = $value;
         break;
         etc....
    }
}

//Default section to set necessary properties if not in database array
foreach($object as $key=>$value)
{
     if($value == null)
     {
            switch ($key)
            {
                case 'property_a':
                     $object->$key = <any value here>;
                     break;
                case 'property_b':
                     $object->$key = <any value here>;
                     break;
                case 'property_c':
                     $object->$key = <any value here>;
                     break;
               etc.....
            }   
     }
}
```

Is there a faster way for these 3 steps? 
Any performance increase is welcome, especially because there are so many of it...

---

Sorry if there are errors in the script, I typed this from head, I dont have the code atm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
$object = new element_class();

//Reinitialize object to remove any set values of object properties to null
foreach($object as $key=>$value)
    $object->$key = null;
```

can be replaced by just

```
$object = new element_class();
```

assuming you define `public $field`s, which are initialized to `null` by default.

This

```
$array = <query from database>
//Switch of array to set the values in the array in the object properties
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    switch($key)
    {
        case 'a':
         $this->property_a = $value;
         break;
        case 'b':
         $this->property_b = $value;
         break;
        case 'c':
         $this->property_c = $value;
         break;
        case 'd':
         $this->property_d = $value;
         break;
         etc....
    }
}
```

can be replaced by

```
$settings = (object) $array;
```

It keeps the settings separate from `$this`, so you can easily save them.

This

```
//Default section to set necessary properties if not in database array
foreach($object as $key=>$value)
     if($value == null)
            switch ($key)
            {
                case 'property_a':
                     $object->$key = <any value here>;
                     break;
                case 'property_b':
                     $object->$key = <any value here>;
                     break;
                case 'property_c':
                     $object->$key = <any value here>;
                     break;
               etc.....
            }
```

should have been done by the `element_class()` constructor as follows:

```
class element_class {
    public $a = <any value here>;
    public $b = <any value here>;
    ....
}
```

You then eliminate the `null` loop (or rather replace it with setting defaults instead), and all you have to do is override them with with the values fetched from `<query>`.

---

Here's a way using php's native `array_merge`:

```
$defaults = [
  'a' => <any value here>,
  'b' => <any value here>,
  ...
];
$array = <query>;
$settings = (object) array_merge( $defaults, $array );
```

I don't know if it's faster, but it is much more easily maintained.
If there is any **speed** concern at all, it should be with **the number of SQL queries**. You say you have *"10"* objects each with around "*15*" rows. You'll get far more speed gain by making that *1* query returning around *150* objects.

Comment: Thank you for your responce. I don't really get the "(object) $array" part. What does it do with the object?

Comment: Oh, that just converts the `array` to a `stdClass`. So, if you have `$a = array( 'foo' => 'bar')`, you would access `foo` by writing `$a['foo']`. With `$b = (object) $a`, you would access it by writing `$b->bar`, which is more convenient, especially within `""` strings: `"... {$a['foo']}..."` vs `"... $b->foo..."`. But it is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `switch`, you can use variable properties, assuming there's a consistent pattern between the property names and the keys of the associative array.

```
$this->{"property_" . $key} = $value;
```

Another option would be to just store all the settings in a single property that contains an associative array. Then you can just do:

```
$this->settings = $array;
```

Comment: Not sure if OP wants to add all array values to the object. And maybe that's why he has a `switch` statement.

Comment: Maybe even `$this->settings = (object) $array;`.

Comment: It address his array iteration to set `$object` properties. I assume OP intends to access the settings using `$object->settings` (a bit easier than `{$object['settings']}` for example).